# iOS Enterprise Build works on <iOS9 but doesn't on iOS9

Tags: xcode, ios9, software-distribution

The issue is simple. I've archived an *.ipa with enterprise certificate. I put it on a server and it works on iOS8, but doesn't on iOS9. It just says it can't be installed . I've built it with XCode7.

Comment: Ran into the same issue at my company.

Comment: Could it be, because ios9 became more strict about the contents of manifest file ? Maybe the bundle id in theanifest has to be exactly the samw as the ipa, including the seed number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michal Ciurus said:

> iOS 9 became more strict with the manifest information:the tag,the
>   value,or something else.

I have met the similar problem.But I think maybe will give you some useful information.

> *The way to find out why,the most important step is to check you device log.It will show you the installation error information.*

```
I find the problem is that I mistake the bundle-identifier value.
```

> I find if you mistake the bundle-identifier value,the iOS 9 will not allow you to install the app,but iOS 8 or lower version will not check bundle-identifier value.

The installation error information from my iOS 9 device:

```
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [Download]: Download task did finish: 8 for download: 2325728577585828282
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace] Installing download: 2325728577585828282 with step(s): Install
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Installing software package with bundleID: com.***.***: bundleVersion: 1.01 path: /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/2325728577585828282/-1925357977307433048
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.***.**** does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.***.*********
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: [ApplicationWorkspace]: Bundle validated for bundleIdentifier: com.****.******success: 0
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling placeholder for app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12677be70> com.****.*******(Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B62D8EA3-2052-4393-8A7E-3FD27228BFC2/2325728577585828282.app>
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x12677be70> com.****.*****(Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B62D8EA3-2052-4393-8A7E-3FD27228BFC2/2325728577585828282.app>
```

Pay attention to the log(I hide the bundle Id because of privacy.):

```
20:40:09 ifeegoo itunesstored →  <Warning>: BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier: com.***.**** does not match expected bundleIdentifier: com.***.*********
```

The most important to solve this problem is to check the device log.

Comment: I guess I was too lazy to look into the logs ;) Thanks. I'll see if it fixes it.

Comment: Haha,the first time when I met the problem,I also didn't check the device log.I guess here and there,and then I found that I can check the log.iOS 9 has lots of pits for developers,be careful!

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks.